# Please help me choose a database design for my project.

Tags: database, database-design, mobile

I want to use a database for a program I'm creating. Let's say that I will have to manage clients that can make "posts" and every post has a series of properties.

To store the information about the users I have created a table. I'm not sure how to design the table for "posts". Every post has some properties that are text and about ten boolean properties.

My question is: Would it be better to have only one column with a Y,N,N,Y.... and then do a split in the program to know every status of these properties or is it better to have every property in a column with a boolean type?

I anticipate large number of clients and a large number of posts so I don't know if this last option is faster and cheaper or not. What do you think? My program will serve data to mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have a column for each of the boolean properties, I would also recommend using a bit, or tinyint column with 1, 0 values instead of Y/N as they take up less space and are easier to manipulate for reporting purposes